# Change Format Date m/d/Y to d/m/Y in Plugin Wordpress code

Tags: php, date, format

I'm using a wordpress plugin for reservations, and this returns the date format m/d/Y even wordpress is set to d/m/Y.

This is the plugin code that displays the calendar:

```
//START week price information
                                        $nd_booking_date_today = date('m/d/Y');

                                        $nd_booking_date_num = new DateTime();
                                        $nd_booking_date_num_n = $nd_booking_date_num->format('N');
                                        $nd_booking_date_num_start = 7+($nd_booking_date_num_n-1);
                                        $nd_booking_date_num_end = 7+(7-$nd_booking_date_num_n);

                                        $nd_booking_date_start = new DateTime('- '.$nd_booking_date_num_start.' days');
                                        $nd_booking_date_start = $nd_booking_date_start->format('m/d/Y');
                                        $nd_booking_date_start_2 = new DateTime($nd_booking_date_start);
                                        $nd_booking_date_start_format = date_format($nd_booking_date_start_2, 'm/d/Y');

                                        $nd_booking_date_end = new DateTime('+ '.$nd_booking_date_num_end.' days');
                                        $nd_booking_date_end = $nd_booking_date_end->format('m/d/Y');
                                        $nd_booking_date_end_2 = new DateTime($nd_booking_date_end);
                                        $nd_booking_date_end_format = date_format($nd_booking_date_end_2, 'm/d/Y');

                                        $nd_booking_date_cicle = $nd_booking_date_start_format;

                                        $nd_booking_result .= '


                                        <style>
                                            
                                            .nd_booking_week_price_icon:hover #nd_booking_week_price { display:block; }

                                            .nd_booking_week_price_first_column { background-color: '.get_option( 'nd_booking_customizer_color_dark_2', '#151515' ).'; }

                                            .nd_booking_week_price_current_column > table { border-left:1px solid '.get_option( 'nd_booking_customizer_color_dark_2', '#151515' ).'; border-right:1px solid '.get_option( 'nd_booking_customizer_color_dark_2', '#151515' ).'; }

                                            .nd_booking_week_price_first_column .nd_booking_week_price_first_line { color:'.get_option( 'nd_booking_customizer_color_1', '#c19b76' ).' !important; }
                                            .nd_booking_week_price_first_column .nd_booking_week_price_second_line { color:'.get_option( 'nd_booking_customizer_color_dark_2', '#151515' ).'; }
                                            
                                            .nd_booking_week_price_first_line {
                                                font-size: 12px;
                                                padding: 10px;
                                                box-sizing: border-box;
                                                background-color: '.get_option( 'nd_booking_customizer_color_1', '#c19b76' ).';
                                                color: #fff !important;
                                                letter-spacing: 2px;
                                                line-height: 12px;
                                            }
                                            .nd_booking_week_price_second_line{
                                                font-size: 11px;
                                                letter-spacing: 2px;
                                                padding: 10px;
                                                box-sizing: border-box;
                                                line-height: 11px;
                                                background-color: '.get_option( 'nd_booking_customizer_color_dark_2', '#151515' ).';
                                            }
                                            .nd_booking_week_price_content p{
                                                font-size:10px;
                                            }

                                            .nd_booking_week_price_content_empty {
                                                color:'.get_option( 'nd_booking_customizer_color_dark_1', '#1c1c1c' ).' !important;
                                            }


                                            .nd_booking_week_price_triangle_down {
                                                width: 100%;
                                                overflow: hidden;
                                                box-sizing: border-box;
                                                text-align: center;
                                                line-height: 10px;
                                                margin-bottom:-10px;
                                            }
                                            .nd_booking_week_price_triangle_down:after {
                                                content: "";
                                                display: inline-block;
                                                width: 0px;
                                                height: 0px;
                                                border-left: 10px solid transparent;
                                                border-right: 10px solid transparent;
                                                border-top: 10px solid '.get_option( 'nd_booking_customizer_color_dark_1', '#1c1c1c' ).';
                                                line-height: 10px;
                                            }

                                        </style>



                                        <div id="nd_booking_week_price" class="nd_booking_width_650 nd_booking_padding_bottom_20 nd_booking_display_none nd_booking_width_300_responsive nd_booking_bottom_50 nd_booking_left_305_negative nd_booking_left_130_negative_responsive nd_booking_float_left nd_booking_position_absolute nd_booking_z_index_9">
                                            <div class="nd_booking_section nd_booking_bg_greydark">
                                        ';

                                                $nd_booking_date_i = 1;
                                                $nd_booking_date_i_2 = 1;
                                                
                                                #while( $nd_booking_date_cicle <= $nd_booking_date_end_format ) {
                                                for ($nd_booking_for_i = 1; $nd_booking_for_i <= 21; $nd_booking_for_i++) {

                                                    $nd_booking_date_week = date("N", strtotime($nd_booking_date_cicle));

                                                    
                                                    //define class for today
                                                    if ( $nd_booking_date_cicle == $nd_booking_date_today ) { $nd_booking_today_class = 'nd_options_color_white'; }else{ $nd_booking_today_class = ''; }

                                                    if ( $nd_booking_date_i_2 == 1 ) {
                                                        $nd_booking_result .= '
                                                            <div class="nd_booking_width_10_percentage nd_booking_display_none_responsive nd_booking_float_left nd_booking_box_sizing_border_box nd_booking_week_price_first_column">
                                                                
                                                                <p class="nd_booking_week_price_first_line">-</p>
                                                                <p class="nd_booking_week_price_second_line">-</p>
                                                            
                                                                <table class="nd_booking_width_100_percentage nd_booking_week_price_content">
                                                                    <tr><td><p>'.__('MON','nd-booking').'</p></td></tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table class="nd_booking_width_100_percentage nd_booking_week_price_content">
                                                                    <tr><td><p>'.__('TUE','nd-booking').'</p></td></tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table class="nd_booking_width_100_percentage nd_booking_week_price_content">
                                                                    <tr><td><p>'.__('WED','nd-booking').'</p></td></tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table class="nd_booking_width_100_percentage nd_booking_week_price_content">
                                                                    <tr><td><p>'.__('THU','nd-booking').'</p></td></tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table class="nd_booking_width_100_percentage nd_booking_week_price_content">
                                                                    <tr><td><p>'.__('FRI','nd-booking').'</p></td></tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table class="nd_booking_width_100_percentage nd_booking_week_price_content">
                                                                    <tr><td><p>'.__('SAT','nd-booking').'</p></td></tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table class="nd_booking_width_100_percentage nd_booking_week_price_content">
                                                                    <tr><td><p>'.__('SUN','nd-booking').'</p></td></tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </div>
                                                        ';
                                                    }

                                                    //open div if week number is 1 and index is 
                                                    if ( $nd_booking_date_i == 1 ) { 


                                                        if ( $nd_booking_date_i_2 == 1 ) {
                                                            $nd_booking_week_word = __('PREV WEEK','nd-booking');   
                                                            $nd_booking_week_class = 'nd_booking_week_price_prev_column';
                                                        }elseif ( $nd_booking_date_i_2 >= 7 and $nd_booking_date_i_2 <= 14 ) {
                                                            $nd_booking_week_word = __('CURRENT WEEK','nd-booking');
                                                            $nd_booking_week_class = 'nd_booking_week_price_current_column';
                                                        }else{
                                                            $nd_booking_week_word = __('NEXT WEEK','nd-booking');
                                                            $nd_booking_week_class = 'nd_booking_week_price_next_column';       
                                                        }


                                                        $nd_booking_result .= '
                                                        <div class="nd_booking_width_30_percentage nd_booking_width_100_percentage_responsive nd_booking_float_left nd_booking_box_sizing_border_box '.$nd_booking_week_class.' ">
                                                            
                                                            <div class="nd_booking_section">
                                                                <div class="nd_booking_section"><p class="nd_booking_week_price_first_line">'.$nd_booking_week_word.'</p></div>
                                                                <div class="nd_booking_width_50_percentage nd_booking_float_left">
                                                                    <p class="nd_booking_week_price_second_line">'.__('DAY','nd-booking').'</p>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="nd_booking_width_50_percentage nd_booking_float_left">
                                                                    <p class="nd_booking_week_price_second_line">'.__('PRICE','nd-booking').'</p>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            '; 
                                                    }

                                                    
                                                    //display data only if week day is ugual to cicle
                                                    if ( $nd_booking_date_week == $nd_booking_date_i ) {

                                                        $nd_booking_result .= '
                                                        <table class="nd_booking_width_100_percentage nd_booking_week_price_content">
                                                            <tr class="'.$nd_booking_today_class.'">
                                                                <td class="nd_booking_width_50_percentage"><p class="'.$nd_booking_today_class.'">'.$nd_booking_date_cicle.'</p></td>
                                                                <td class="nd_booking_width_50_percentage"><p class="'.$nd_booking_today_class.'">'.nd_booking_get_final_price($nd_booking_id,$nd_booking_date_cicle).' '.nd_booking_get_currency().'</p></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        ';

                                                        $nd_booking_date_cicle = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($nd_booking_date_cicle.' + 1 days'));

                                                    }else{

                                                        $nd_booking_result .= '
                                                        <table class="nd_booking_width_100_percentage nd_booking_week_price_content">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="nd_booking_width_50_percentage"><p class="nd_booking_week_price_content_empty">-</p></td>
                                                                <td class="nd_booking_width_50_percentage"><p class="nd_booking_week_price_content_empty">-</p></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        ';

                                                        $nd_booking_date_cicle = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($nd_booking_date_cicle.' + 1 days'));
                                                        $nd_booking_date_cicle = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($nd_booking_date_cicle.' - 1 days'));  

                                                    }

                                                

                                                    if ( $nd_booking_date_week == 7 ) { 
                                                        $nd_booking_result .= '</div>'; 
                                                        $nd_booking_date_i = 1;
                                                    }else{
                                                        $nd_booking_date_i = $nd_booking_date_i+1;
                                                    }

                                                    $nd_booking_date_i_2 = $nd_booking_date_i_2+1;
                                                                        
                                                }
                                                    

                                            $nd_booking_result .= '

                                            <div class="nd_booking_week_price_triangle_down"></div>                                             
                                            
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        ';
                                        
                                        //END week price information
```

Not being a programmer, I tried to replace all m/d/Y with d/m/Y, but it gives me blank page/error.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing only the following

```
 <td class="nd_booking_width_50_percentage"><p class="'.$nd_booking_today_class.'">'.$nd_booking_date_cicle.'</p></td>
```

To

```
 <td class="nd_booking_width_50_percentage"><p class="'.$nd_booking_today_class.'">'.date('d/m/Y',strtotime($nd_booking_date_cicle)).'</p></td>
```

From what I can tell, this seems to be the only section that is displaying the date, so only editing this section will not affect code of other sections

Comment: Note I edited my answer as I missed strtotime